# Python: MySQLdb: Error: 1064 "You have an error in your SQL syntax."

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm new to MySQLdb and Python. I'm trying to execute the following statement:

```
header_string = 'number_one, number_two, number_three'
values = '1, 2, 3'
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO my_table (%s) VALUES (%s)""", (header_string, values))
```

and it returns with the following error:

**Error: 1064 "You have an error in your SQL syntax."**

From my limited understanding of MySQLdb the above execute statement should execute the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (number_one, number_two, number_three) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: SQL doesn't allow variables to represent comma delimited values at runtime -- if you create the SQL query as a string & use the variables in Python before submitting the query, it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
header_string = ('number_one','number_two','number_three')
values = (1,2,3)
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO my_table (%s,%s,%s) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", (header_string+values))
```

Comment: That is still not going to work. MySQLdb escapes strings so that no SQL injection can occur in your code. That _query_ will be translated into `INSERT INTO my_table("number_one", "number_two", "number_three") VALUES (1, 2, 3)`, which is also syntactically wrong.

Comment: Actually it'll be translated into: `INSERT INTO my_table(\`number_one\`, ...)`. Apparently it did work, since the answer was accepted.

Comment: My bad. I really thought mysqldb changed any string into its quoted form, and was unaware that it correctly handled column names. One learns new stuff every day :)